# MySQL syntax in Hibernate - what's wrong?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to make an update query in HQL, but in doesn't work, I'm using MySQL5Dialect. In Patient class all variables are annotated just like column's names in database. Here is a code:

```
Controller:
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("clinic");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Patient patient = new Patient();

    patient.setFirstName(infonameField.getText());
    patient.setLastName(infolastNameField.getText());
    patient.setGender(infogenderField.getText());
    patient.setAge(infoageField.getText());
    patient.setPhonenumber(infophonenumberField.getText());
    patient.setAddress(infoadressField.getText());
    patient.setDisease(infodiseaseField.getText());
    patient.setCondition(infoconditionField.getText());
    patient.setRoomtype(infoRoomType.getText());
    patient.setRoomNumber(infoRoomNumber.getText());
    patient.setDateregistration(infodataField.getText());
    patient.setIdpatient(infoPIDField.getText());

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Patient set name = :name, lastname= :lastname,"
            + "gender= :gender, age= :age, phonenumber= :phonenumber, address= :address, disease= :disease,"
            + "condition= :condition, roomtype= :roomtype, roomnumber= :roomnumber, "
            + "dateregistration= :dateregistration WHERE idpatient= :idpatient");

    query.setParameter("name", patient.getFirstName());
    query.setParameter("lastname", patient.getLastName());
    query.setParameter("gender", patient.getGender());
    query.setParameter("age", patient.getAge());
    query.setParameter("phonenumber", patient.getPhonenumber());
    query.setParameter("address", patient.getAddress());
    query.setParameter("disease", patient.getDisease());
    query.setParameter("condition", patient.getCondition());
    query.setParameter("roomtype", patient.getRoomtype());
    query.setParameter("roomnumber", patient.getRoomNumber());
    query.setParameter("dateregistration", patient.getDateregistration());
    query.setParameter("idpatient", patient.getIdpatient());
    query.executeUpdate();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition='ewqewqeq', roomtype='standard', roomnumber='101', dateregistration='2' at line 1
```

Comment: You're probably missing a space between `disease= :disease,` and `condition= :condition`.

Comment: I cut query since "condition" till the end, and everything was fine, when I added just only condition=:condition the problem appears again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `condition` is a [keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-condition.html) in MySQL, probably that's the reason of your error. Try modifying it or replace it by another name.

**EDIT**

After reading [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,40643,40643) MySQL forum post, you can use it as long as you escape it, as mentioned [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,40643,40702#msg-40702).